# Need to control some device via Wi-Fi using C#

Tags: c#, wifi

I am working on an application that needs to control another device.

This control should be using [Wi-Fi](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wi-Fi).

How can this be done in C#?

Important to know that the other device I want to make it.

I can afford the part of making and design but how to make it connect to PC using Wi-Fi?

I don't know about it.

I just need a key to start searching or some thing similar.

Comment: how small is this other device?

Answer (score 7):

Connecting over [Wi-Fi](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wi-Fi) could be as easy as opening a socket on the server, and another on the client, and start streaming data. Of course this if both devices are compatible and has Wi-Fi receivers. Just think of them as two computers connected with a wire, or without a wire they will just behave the same.

The connection protocol will care about doing the magic of converting what you write on the socket, into RF signals received from the other device and converted back to bytes.

But if you are building your own antenna/receiver/protocol ... then things will be much more complicated.

Comment: thanks for your answer ,need to install a airless card on my circuit 
is that possible?  
secondly can U speak more technical like libraries I may need under C#?

Comment: Actually I don't know a bit of C# :(

but in general if you get some wireless circuit to install on your device (google for them) you will get their own help/documentation on how to use it. and for sure you will have pieces of code too, and  their own libraries.

Answer (score -2):

If you have to ask then you're probably going to want a single board computer. Popular choices are:

- [gumstix](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gumstix)
- [Zii EGG](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zii_EGG)
- nwg100 by Atmel
- (XBee)  --not too sure about these, I haven't used.

You can install a network stack and everything on them.